# Securing of passwords in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

A financially regulated business partner would like to understand some of the details of how a user's password are maintained (hashing algorithms etc) in Azure AD B2C. Can anyone share any insight on this.

I can find information on how Azure AD syncs passwords on articles like this https://www.dsinternals.com/en/how-azure-active-directory-connect-syncs-passwords/ but not how a cloud based password is secured.

Thanks Michael

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more apropriate for [Information Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD B2C is just active directory in the backend. See this blog post for how it handles passwords:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/034a0e33-a8ab-474e-ba6c-3371724d0be1/forum-faq-how-is-user-password-of-user-objects-stored-in-active-directory-can-i-view-it-can-i?forum=winserverDS

**Excerpt:**

The users' password hash is stored in the Active Directory on a user object in the unicodePwd attribute. Instead of storing your user account password in clear-text, Windows generates and stores user account passwords by using two different password representations, generally known as "hashes." When you set or change the password for a user account to a password that contains fewer than 15 characters, Windows generates both a LAN Manager hash (LM hash) and a Windows NT hash (NT hash) of the password. These hashes are stored in the local Security Accounts Manager (SAM) database or in Active Directory.

This unicodePwd attribute can be written under restricted conditions, but it cannot be read due to security reasons. The attribute can only be modified; it cannot be added on object creation or queried by a search. In order to modify this attribute, the client must have a 128-bit Secure Socket Layer (SSL) connection to the server. For this connection to be possible, the server must possess a server certificate for a 128-bit RSA connection, the client must trust the certificate authority (CA) that generated the server certificate, and both client and server must be capable of 128-bit encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I have a funny feeling this is something Microsoft will never tell you for security reasons.

You cant even recover a password from Azure AD

Comment: You can reset (change) a password in AD. You can't view a password (if that's what you mean by "recover" because it's hashed. This is common and recommended practice for password storage.